# Fast Way to Update part of Excel worksheet from C# Interop Add In

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-interop, excel-addins

I'm trying to find a fast way to update an Excel Spreadsheet (C# Interop). This is an Excel Add In and the worksheet will have about 20000 rows when fully populated. My current process is as follows:

- I subscribe to a service for events
- When I get the first event I process a State of the World where I fill an array and rapidly fill the spreadsheet. This takes a few seconds to complete but the performance is fine. At the same time I fill a Dictionary with a key and a class containing the Excel address and Cell value.
- Subsequent events I receive should be considered updates/inserts. This means I need to iterate through my Dictionary and see what has changed (this is fast enough). The slow part is the code below where I get the Excel range in a loop and update the changed value:

  ```
  Globals.MyAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating = false;
  XL.Range add1 = activeWorksheet.get_Range(xlDataPoint.ExcelAddress);
  xlDataPoint.Value = value.ToString();
  add1.Value2 = value;
  Globals.MyAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating = true;
  ```
- Since some cells change and others dont - I only want to update those where the value has changed. I also need to keep the worksheet responsive to the user.
  What can I do to speed up the updating of my spreadsheet (I suspect the answer would be the same in VBA or C#.)?

Comment: Tried moving the screenupdating calls outside of your loop? (assuming from your posted code they are per-cell calls)

Comment: Tim, the difference was not material, I am able however to assign to larger ranges and this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see three ways to increase speed. First - follow advice of Tim Williams and move ScreenUpdating calls outside of loop. Second - if your cells are sequences, assign values to all of them at once, using [Range.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value.aspx) property:

```
object[,] example = new object[2,2] { {1, 2}, { 3, 4}};
activeWorksheet.Range[activeWorksheet.Cells[1,1], activeWorksheet.Cells[2,2]].Value = example;
```

Another way, if value in many cells is the same, to use Application.Union Function to get many cells as one range and assign values at once.

Comment: Yes I am able to assign to a range of cells as you point out. The ScreenUpdating did not make a material difference.